# Error when loading tensorflow.js with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I am fairly new to javascript. I am working through the [tensorflow-js tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/index.html#getting-started) on using tensorflow-js with node.js however when I run the example code:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');

// Load the binding:
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');  // Use '@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu' if running with GPU.

// Train a simple model:
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu', inputShape: [10]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'linear'}));
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

const xs = tf.randomNormal([100, 10]);
const ys = tf.randomNormal([100, 1]);

model.fit(xs, ys, {
  epochs: 100,
  callbacks: {
    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, log) => {
      console.log(`Epoch ${epoch}: loss = ${log.loss}`);
    }
  }
});
```

I have already installed the tensorflowjs package:
    npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu

However I get the error:

```
module.js:549
throw err;
Error: Cannot find module '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'
```

I am not sure what is causing this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to:

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

Comment: This worked! Would you mind adding a small comment about what this command does - as it is not listed in the tensorflowjs installation instructions

Comment: Its right there in the installation instructions https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node#installing-cpu-tensorflowjs-for-node

Comment: it does not mention --save

Comment: Right, you probably don't need that if installing from an existing package.json

Comment: ```// Load the binding:
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');  // Use '@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu' if running with GPU.```
Right there in the comments of the code.
You can use `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` or if using a GPU with CUDA you can use `@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu` - install the approriate one. They are mutually exclusive.